# AVAssetWriterInput appendSampleBuffer crashing

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avcapturesession, avassetwriter

I have an audioWriterBuffer to which I am appending audio sample buffers as follows

```
func captureOutput(captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputSampleBuffer sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer!, fromConnection connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {

    if CMSampleBufferDataIsReady(sampleBuffer) <= 0 {
        return
    }

    if captureOutput == audioOutput && audioWriterBuffer != nil && audioWriterBuffer.readyForMoreMediaData == true {
        var audioTime = CMSampleBufferGetPresentationTimeStamp(sampleBuffer)
        audioWriterBuffer.appendSampleBuffer(sampleBuffer)
    }
}
```

It works as it is supposed to. However every once in a while, it crashes with the following error:

> NSArray was mutated while being enumerated.

at:

```
audioWriterBuffer.appendSampleBuffer(sampleBuffer)
```

I don't understand the relevance of that, or how to solve it.

Any clue?

Comment: On which line does it crash? Are you sure it's crashing in this code and not elsewhere?

Comment: Yes. Debugger stops there.

Comment: Crashes when I try to append the sample buffer

Comment: Did you solve this? I have a similar issue. It crashes at the same place with: "terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException" when I call cancelWriting().

Comment: Did you get the solution to this? I am facing the same crash. @JosephK